# how to add library to static resource

Tags: static-resources, static

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >

<apex:form >
<script type="text/javascript" url="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script url="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            title: "jQuery Dialog",
            width: 300,
            height: 150
        });
        $("#btnShow").click(function () {alert("hi");
        console.log()
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show Popup" />
<div id="dialog" style="display: none" align = "center">
    This is a jQuery Dialog.
</div>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

hi, i am getting error library not included, how can i include that library in my static resource thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As HTTPS is used by Salesforce, requests to include scripts via HTTP are usually blocked by browsers.

Change `http://` to `https://` in the URLs if you don't want to add static resource copies.

Answer (score 2):

In `Setup > Develop > Static resources`, you can create your static resource uploading your library file.

And then, in your page, you need to include it :

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.YOUR_STATIC_RESOURCE_NAME}" />
```